# how to use trigger.adddependencies in pyzabbix

Tags: python, zabbix

i'm a newbie in python and coding,i'm trying to use pyzabbix to add trigger dependecies,but some error occusrs.

When i run

```
zapi.trigger.addDependencies(triggerid, dependsOnTriggerid)
```

an error occurs

```
pyzabbix.ZabbixAPIException: ('Error -32500: Application error., No permissions to referred object or it does not exist!', -32500)
```

i get the "triggerid" and "dependsOnTriggerid" by trigger.get:

```
triggerid_info = zapi.trigger.get(filter={'host': 'xx','description': 'xx'},output=['triggerid'], selectDependencies=['description'])

triggerid = triggerid_info[0]['triggerid']

dependsOnTriggerid = trigger_info[0]['dependencies'][0]['triggerid']
```

The results are as follws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:/10.python/2019-03-07/1.py", line 14, in zapi.trigger.addDependencies(triggerid, dependsOnTriggerid) File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyzabbix__init__.py", line 166, in fn args or kwargs File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyzabbix__init__.py", line 143, in do_request raise ZabbixAPIException(msg, response_json['error']['code']) pyzabbix.ZabbixAPIException: ('Error -32500: Application error., No permissions to referred object or it does not exist!', -32500)
```

Did i get the wrong triggerid? or the i use the method in a wrong way? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a dependancy means that you need to link two different triggers (from the same host or from another one) with a master-dependent logic.

You are trying to add the dependancy `triggerid -> dependsOnTriggerid`, which is obtained from a supposed existing dependancy (`trigger_info[0]['dependencies'][0]['triggerid']`), and this makes little sense and I suppose it's the cause of the error.

You need to get both trigger's `triggerid` and then add the dependancy:

```
masterTriggerObj = zapi.trigger.get( /* filter to get your master trigger here */ )
dependentTriggerObj = zapi.trigger.get( /* filter to get your dependent trigger here */)

result = zapi.trigger.adddependencies(triggerid=dependentTriggerObj[0]['triggerid'], dependsOnTriggerid=masterTriggerObj[0]['triggerid'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I've solved the problem. The method "trigger.addDependencies" need only one parameter，and it should be a dict or some other object/array.I have put my code in the answer. Thanks .

Comment: The code you added is practically the same as mine. Note that calling `addDependancies` with a single dict (your `trigger_dependson_193`) or with `triggerid=dependentTriggerObj[0]['triggerid'], dependsOnTriggerid=masterTriggerObj[0]['triggerid']` is the same, so "need only one parameter" isn't correct.

Comment: OH great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The method "trigger.addDependencies" need only one parameter，and it should be a dict or some other object/array.The following code solves the problem.

`trigger_info = zapi.trigger.get(filter={xx},output=['triggerid'])`

`trigger_depends_info_193 = zapi.trigger.get(filter={xx},output=['triggerid'])`

`trigger_dependson_193 = {"triggerid": trigger_info[0]['triggerid'], "dependsOnTriggerid": trigger_depends_info_193[0]['triggerid']}`

`zapi.trigger.adddependencies(trigger_dependson_193)`